# how to get user profile from linked in using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2, linkedin-api

How do you get the user profile after you have finish verification in linkedin? I've been googling around and found some tutorials but none of them are working, or should I say I can't get them to work. Below is my controller.

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->config->load('linkedin');

    $this->data['consumer_key'] = $this->config->item('api_key');
    $this->data['consumer_secret'] = $this->config->item('secret_key');
    $this->data['callback_url'] = site_url() . 'main/linkedin_display';
}

function linkedin_request(){

    $this->load->library('linkedin', $this -> data);

    $token = $this->linkedin->get_request_token();

    $oauth_data = array(
        'oauth_request_token' => $token['oauth_token'],
        'oauth_request_token_secret' => $token['oauth_token_secret']
        );

    $this->session->set_userdata($oauth_data);

    $request_link = $this->linkedin->get_authorize_URL($token);

    header("Location: " . $request_link);

}

function linkedin_display{

    // get user details(first name, email etc) here

}
```

Comment: what is the linkedin library you're using?

Comment: [this one](https://github.com/MurrionSoftware/codeigniter-linkedin-library)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following function to your linkedin library, in order to get data

```
function getData($url, $access_token)
{

    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $access_token, "GET", $url);
    $request->sign_request($this->method, $this->consumer, $access_token);
    $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");

    $response = $this->httpRequest($shareUrl, $auth_header, "GET");

    return $response;
}
```

Then create a function in your controller as follows:

```
/**
 * Fetch linkedin profile
 */
function myprofile()
{
    $auth_data = $this->session->userdata('auth');

    $this->load->library('linkedin', $this->data);

    $status_response = $this->linkedin->getData('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~', unserialize($auth_data['linked_in']));


    print_r($status_response);

}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: it requires more than one parameter. What are the rest?

Comment: I did some research and changed my answer. Please check now.

Comment: I tried your code it says $sharedUrl not defined so I changed it to $url since in your getData function the params are `$url, $access_token` the error is gone, but another error appeared. It says 'Could not find person based on: ~' still googling around to fix this error, If I find the solution will post it here. Thanks for your effort helping me out.

Comment: This function will not work except after authenticating via Linkedin, by accessing the index function of the user controller, since your access token is stored inside a session, not your database. Did you do that before executing this function?

Comment: Yes sir. I first authenticated the user before running the `getData` function.

Comment: You can look at the codes from my question. The `linkedin_requestion` function is called to authenticate the user and after finishing authentication the 'myprofile' function is called to display the user info.

Comment: Do other linkedin API commands work if you call getData with a different first parameter such as `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/162479`?

Comment: i get an error `400 400 1363054099876 E7N306SABM 0 Invalid value {162479)} in key {id} 400 1363054099876 E7N306SABM 0 Invalid value {162479)} in key {id}`

Comment: What do the following variables contain when you call myprofile()?: 1)$this->session->userdata('auth'); 2) $this->data

Comment: the $this->data contains `consumer_key, consumer_secret and callback_url`. I'm not sure about `$this->session->userdata('auth')` because it's from your `myprofile` function.